# Error parsing XML, The content of elements must consist of well-formed character data or markup

Tags: xml

I'm trying to build a custom template for a blog. This is the code that I have:

```
<$BlogDateHeaderDate$>
</div>
</BlogDateHeader>
```

Trying desperately to get the layout to work for my new blog and I have ran into a lot of errors in the html/xml

If anyone has any suggestions I am most definitely open to them!

Comment: I'm not sure about your context, but maybe you need to replace < with &lt; and > with &gt;?

Comment: Looks as though you're trying to use some templating language that looks like XML but isn't XML, and then you're putting these non-XML documents into an XML parser.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're trying to use a template like in: https://www.blogit.com/Blogs/Help/HelpPage.aspx?page=templatedesign

The `<$BlogDateHeaderDate$>` bit will be replaced by a string like `Monday, August 26, 2002`. Is this `Monday...` acceptable text in your template?
In your sample you've included two closing tags, but no opening tags.. A complete, basic template would look like:

```
<BlogTemplate>
     <BlogDateHeader>
          <$BlogDateHeaderDate$>
     </BlogDateHeader>

     <PostSubject>
          <$BlogItemSubject$ >
     </PostSubject>

     <$BlogItemBody$>
     <$BlogItemAuthor$>
     <$BlogItemAuthorNickname$>
     <$BlogItemAuthorEmail$>
     <$BlogItemAuthorURL$>
     <$BlogItemDateTime$>
     <$BlogItemNumber$>

     <BlogDateFooter>
     </BlogDateFooter>
</BlogTemplate>
```